# separate user input into tags whenver "," key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want users input to be separated into tags whenever "," key is pressed.

How can i do that without jquery using div and contenteditable.

Comment: check keyCode is `188` inside handler

Comment: Simpler to just check for ',' as the user inputs text. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attach a key listener to your div:

```
div.addEventListener("input", function(){
    var text = div.textContent;
    var tags = text.split(",");
    //do rest of stuff.
});
```

the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) fires when contenteditable elements are changing. you can use it in combination with keydown events to get more control.